# Proper syntax for container.dataitem binding to A Href tag

Tags: asp.net, itemtemplate, datacolumn

I have a Datagrid with an ItemTemplate in it to convert a dataitem to a link. However, when I run the app it errors out with:

> FolderID is neither a DataColumn nor a DataRelation for table Table.

Here is the line of code in question:

```
  <b><a href="PerformanceEvaluationSubcontractorRating.aspx?ProjectID='<%#Container.DataItem("ProjectID")%>'&FolderID='<%#Container.DataItem("FolderID")%>'&SubcontractorID='<%#Container.DataItem("OrganizationID")%>'>
  <%#Container.DataItem("OrganizationName")%>
  </a></b>
```

What is wrong with the A Href tag?

Comment: Whats your query used to populate your DataTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FolderID column is not present at the datasource. This error has nothing to do with the A Href tag, it is a databinding error. check the schema to retrieve the right column name.

Comment: I was under the impression it was referring to the "&FolderID=" part. The query was returning folder_id instead of folderID. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ensure your field is part of your table (ie part of your query to populate the table)